# wordpress plugins - handling variables

Tags: wordpress, variables, plugins

I wrote a simple twitter connect plugin which needs to display the 'logged in' user's name in the header after he logs in.  The function is working properly but I am unable to display the $user variable in my header or anywhere outside the function even though it is assigned global.

Here is the end of the login function:

```
$user= $Twitter->get_accountVerify_credentials();
print_r($user);
// show screen name (not real name)
$twitter_user = $user->screen_name;
// show profile image url
$twitter_image = $user->profile_image_url;
```

I can see that it is successful because the $user gets printed, but when I call it in my header.php file the same way I can an error: Notice: Undefined variable: user

Any suggestions?

Comment: In which file did you declare the $Twitter variable? Most likely the $user variable in header is called before it's actually declared

Comment: $twitter is being declared in a function and hooked like this: add_action('init','twitter_logged_in');
I believe the header is called after this..

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to getting wrapped up in the scope of the variables, I'd write a function to get this information. Something like:

```
function get_twitter_user_name(){
    $user= $Twitter->get_accountVerify_credentials();
    return $user->screen_name;
}
```

Then, in the header, where I want to display the name, I'd call the function like so:

```
<?php echo get_twitter_user_name(); ?>
```

Depending on the structure of your code, this may look a little different than what I have here, but hopefully this will give you another way of tackling this problem.